# Is it possible to use Elastic Beanstalk without a runtime?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk for its load-balancing and auto-scaling features. However, I am deploying a Linux binary, so I do not need .NET, Node.js, JVM, etc. My understanding is that these slow down deployments, so I would prefer not to use them at all.

I am currently using Node.js, but is it possible to use Elastic Beanstalk without any run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Beanstalk's [custom platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html) feature. Basically, custom platforms are a way of using your own Amazon Machine Image (AMI) to create Beanstalk environments with. For your purpose, it sounds like what you could do is create a base AMI, perhaps with the necessary Linux binaries installed especially if they are going to be static over time.

The advantage, of course, is that you don't need expensive runtimes/unnecessary configurations.

[Here's](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-custom-platforms-samples/tree/master/NodePlatform_RHEL) an example of a custom platform.